# How to restore last route in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a Flutter app and I have a problem.
In my main.dart I set a home route that is "FirstScreen", then the user can go to the LoginScreen to sign into the account. So if I press the home button and then I try to re-open the app the screen that appear is FirstScreen, so how can I show the last route the user have seen?

I've searched on Flutter docs and on other question in StackOverflow for some solutions but I found nothing that work for me.

This is my main.dart build.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FirstScreen(),
      routes: {
        '/screen1' : (context) => Screen1(),
        '/homeScreen' : (context) => HomeScreen(navigatorKey: navigatorKey,),
        '/registerScreen' : (context) => RegisterScreen(),
        '/screen2' : (context) => Screen2(),
        '/firstScreen' : (context) => FirstScreen(),
        '/userProfileScreen' : (context) => UserProfileScreen(),
      },
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've find a solution, using WidgetBindingObserver, and put this line : `WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);` inside every StatefulWidget initState.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to keep track of the latest route the user has visited and store that somewhere persistent so that it survives app restarts. Perhaps look at the shared preferences package as a simple approach:

https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences

When the app starts, look in shared preferences to see if you have the previous route stored, and navigate to it (or set it as the home route). If not, fall back to the FirstScreen as a default.